# Show uploaded images in full size

Tags: images, templates, the-content

I have a very simple template where I am showing images. The code looks like this:

```
<?php 
/*
* Template Name: Portfolio
*/
 ?>

 <?php get_header(); ?>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php 

        the_content();

        ?>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div> <!-- #small-12 -->
 </div> <!-- #row -->

 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The problem is that when I upload my images in the editor, they become much smaller than they actually are (on the page). I control their size by setting `max-width: 100%` in my css already, so I don't want WordPress to limit the size. How can I remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress creates 3 different sizes as far as my research goes. Read this on WP image handling -> http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/web-development/wordpress-featured-images-add_image_size-resizing-and-cropping-demo/

> You can easily customise the default Media sizes by changing the default sizes in Dashboard > Settings > Media.

You can grab any of those sizes. See the codex @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

The function you want is:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr )
```

And here's an example:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);                  // without parameter -> Thumbnail

get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');     // Thumbnail
get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'medium');        // Medium resolution
get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large');         // Large resolution
get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'full');          // Original resolution

get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array(100,100) ); // Other resolutions
```